# Problem with customer group on multi-site

Tags: magento-1.9, customer-group

I am having an issue because I cannot create a new user. The admin panel is telling me the "Group" is required but there is no drop down which I could use to select a group.

Is there any modification to do in the code to get this appearing? How should I proceed to find the cause of this problem.

[image]

Thank for the help in advance.

Comment: Customer group comes in Magento by default. You might have installed some extension that is stopping it from appearing.

Comment: Hmm. Not really but created some. If you have any idea how to start debugging that would help me a lot.

Comment: I'd suggest try disabling them one by one and see, disabling which shows the customer group back in the form. I hope you have not modified any core files!

Comment: Nope we didnt. I tried to disable those 2 modules that relates to customer, but still the group wont show up. If you know how this is managed internally, maybe we can add debug logs to see what is going on.

Comment: You can enable hints in admin via this link : http://www.classyllama.com/blog/enable-templateblock-hints-in-admin-panel. If customer form is coming from default locations, then you might have setup used_in_forms of customer_group somewhere incorrect, otherwise it will show up the templates over-riding default ones.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That helped me. I figured out the group rendered was not in the template anymore for some reason.

Comment: Please add the solution to the question below and accept it as an answer, so that it doesn't add upto the list of unanswered questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my issue.
The files under adminhtml/base/default/template/customer/edit/tab/ for some reason disappeared.
Copying the files from Magento install package in this directory fixed my issue.

Thanks to Prateek who guided me on this.